# Attach string where condition in linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
string StrWhere = string.Empty;
StrWhere = " AND ID =5";
String StrQuery ="SELECT * FROM CITY_MAS WHERE + StrWhere";
```

I want to achieve the same in LINQ. Something along the lines of the following query...

```
var result = from c in db.CITY_MAS   
         where + StrWhere
         select new { c.ID,c.Name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Dynamic Linq to dynamically add criteria.

See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can either use DynamicLINQ (works also with LINQ to SQL) - see [Maarten's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14535444/266919) - or you can use the following method:

The `ObjectQuery<T>` contains a `Where` method that allows to define a string custom predicate. So, your query could be re-written as follows:

```
var strWhere = "it.ID = 5";
var result = objSet.Where(strWhere);
```

In the where clause the `it` refers to the current object/table - analogous to `this` in c#. The `objSet` is an `ObjectSet<CITY>` (which inherits from `ObjectQuery<T>`).

Depending, whether you use an `ObjectContext` or a `DbContext` the ways to get to `objSet` are different:

- ObjectContext

In an `ObjectContext` `CITY` already would be an `ObjectSet<CITY>` so there is no real additional action needed, so:

```
var objSet = db.CITY;
```

- DbContext (EF Code First)

Here `CITY` is a `DbSet<CITY>` and the described override for the `Where` method is not available. However, each `DbContext` has an underlying `ObjectContext` you can use to do some more complex queries. You just have to get to it and then create the `ObjectSet`:

```
// assuming: using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

var var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).db;
var objSet = objContext.CreateObjectSet<CITY>();
```

See also [this blog post](http://zeitknecht.de/2012/07/21/sorting-with-entity-framework-code-first-and-mvc/) for additional uses.
Full documentation on the `ObjectSet<T>.Where` method can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811.aspx).